# Does installing mysqli mean my mysql queries won't work anymore?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm about to start work converting my mysql queries to mysqli, and am wondering if installing mysqli will kill all my currrent mysql queries? Or do they play nicely together so that I can convert to mysqli over the next few weeks without killing all the mysql on my test server?

Comment: Your mysql queries will continue to work.

Comment: No, you don't lose anything and `mysql_*`, `mysqli` and `PDO` are by default installed with any new PHP version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your are talking about php extension. mysql extension is [deprecated as of php 5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) It will work for now but eventually it should be removed. So for now you can convert to mysqli over the next few weeks.

Comment: Very likely `next few years`